# Getting Null Values in C# controller through Ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax

```
function unlockJob(jobrunid, entityId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/management/redis_locks/' +jobrunid + entityId,
        data: '{' + jobrunid + entityId + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
        dateType:"json",
        body: jobrunid,
        success: function () {
            $("#" + jobrunid + "").append("<span style='color:green'>Unlocked Successfully</span>");
            $("#button"+ jobrunid + "").hide();
        }
    });
} 
    //This is Controller method i am calling
[POST("redis_locks/{entity_id}")]
    [AccessLevelAuthorizationFilter(MinimalAccessLevel = AccessLevel.Admin)]
    public JsonResult UnlockJob(String JobrunId, String entityId)
    {
        _redisRepository.ReleaseLock(RedisKeys.JobRunner.GenericEntityLock(entityId, _cacheKeyBuilder.Prefix));
        var model = true;
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is the Javascript code and C# code which I am calling and then I am not able to get values in Controller when i give a call from the above ajax function..!!

Comment: You need to send an actual object instead of a string that looks a little bit like JSON.

Comment: Why are you passing `AllowGet` in a POST action?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' does not contain a definition for 'AllowPost'    this is the error i get when I tried AllowPost

Comment: That's the default.  That parameter is optional.

Comment: I removed it but still I am getting null at backend..!!

Comment: That's because you aren't actually passing any properties.  You need to pass an object in your JS code.

Comment: can u suggest an example..sorry i am new to ajax and C#..!!

Comment: Thanks @SLaks I got it..thanks for suggesting..:)